# How to use countif on different sheets in the same workbook

Tags: excel

I hope everyone is fine.

I have a workbook with 5 different sheets:

Sheet1: Named Paris
Sheet2: Named London
Sheet3: Named Berlin
Sheet4: Named New York
Sheet5: Name Rome

In the cell C3 of each tab I have the answer to a question that I put in cell B3 also on each tab. What I want to do is to count all the cells that contain "No".

I have used the following formula and it has given me a value error:

```
=Countif(Paris:Rome!C3,"No")
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",1,Paris:Rome!C3)&"</b></a>","//b")="No"))`

or

`=LET(ω,"|"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,Paris:Rome!C3),QUOTIENT(LEN(ω)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(ω,"|No","")),LEN("|No")))`

Comment: Thank you Jos. I would like to ask why my function did not work. In relation to your two formulas? What´s the difference between using N and - - ? Why did you use <> ?  Regarding the second one, what are the ω and | for?

Comment: @viewotst `N` function returns a number when given a value. `N` function can be used to convert TRUE and FALSE to 1 and 0 respectively. When given a text value, the N function returns zero, while double negative (sometimes called the even more nerdy "double unary") coerces TRUE or FALSE values to their numeric equivalents, 1 and 0. It's used in formulas where numbers are needed for a particular math operation.

Comment: @viewotst and regarding the `ω` is a name assigned when using the `LET` function, it can be any letter and its a variable assigned while `|` is used a delimiter in `TEXTJOIN` Function!

Comment: @Jos Woolley Sir, i might not be able to provide a proper explanation, but your explanation might be best to clear more for OP's clarity and please don't mind i have commented, i found the solution useful and hence voted for the same!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Many thanks for providing detailed explanations in response to the OP's questions.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for your help. However, I am not familiar with some of the functions you have used. If we look at the second option: We are giving the name "w" to a function that is doing this No|Yes|No|Yes|No? Why this | delimiter instead of a comma?  Then, the second name to assign is the Quotient function which is going to give us the integer number of the len of No|Yes|No|Yes|No substituting "|No" for a space = Len w is 17 - 8 = 9 ; then divided it by Len of No = 3. In a nutshell, we count all the text, we substract the No and we divided by the No?

Comment: I have not tried the first option yet. And why the function countif does not work?

Comment: `COUNTIF` does not accept a 3D reference (i.e. multi-sheet) for the range parameter.

Comment: `LET` is not essential - it just avoids unnecessary repetition in formulas.

Comment: Use of a delimiter is good practice in general. If we instead just search for 'No', this could result in a false positive for cells containing, for example, 'None'. Use of a delimiter excludes such possibilities.